# Integral of a generalized inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inverse-function

Let $s$ be a **positive decreasing** function, why does

$v s^{\leftarrow}(v) + \int_{s^{\leftarrow}(v)}^{\infty} s(u) \: \mathrm{d}u = \int_{0}^{v} s^{\leftarrow}(u) \: \mathrm{d}u \tag{*} $

hold? $s^{\leftarrow}(x)$ is here the generalized inverse function, so

\begin{align}
s^{\leftarrow}(x)=\text{inf}\{y:s(y) \ge x  \}.
\end{align}

I know for $s^{-1}$ as the inverse function of $s$ and $S$ the antiderivative of $s$, we have

\begin{align}
\int s^{-1} (u) \: \mathrm{d}u = us^{-1}(u) - S(s^{-1}(u)) + C. \tag{**}
\end{align}
If we have $s^{\leftarrow}$ as the inverse function and not just the generalized one, I see that $(**)$ implicates $(*)$, but with $s^{\leftarrow}$ as generalized inverse function, I don't see, why $s^{\leftarrow}(0)=\text{inf}\{y:s(y) \ge 0\}$ should be $\infty$.

I hope someone can help me out.

Sources:

[Link 1 (p. 79ff)](https://books.google.de/books?id=catZCl17d7gC&lpg=PA79&hl=de&pg=PA79#v=onepage&q&f=false)

[Link 2 (p. 162ff)](http://d-nb.info/1079391835/34)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $n$ consider the function $s_n(v)=s(v)+\frac1ng(v)$, where $g$ is positive and strictly decreasing and integrable. Then $s_n$ is strictly increasing and so since you proved that (*) holds for strictly increasing functions you have that
$$v s^{-1}_n(v)+\int^\infty_{s^{-1}_n(v)}s_n(u)\,du=\int_0^v s^{-1}_n(u)\,du.$$
Now you have to use the fact that as $n\to\infty$, $s^{-1}_n(v)\to s^{\rightarrow}(v)$ (see this link [convergence generalized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517134/convergence-of-generalized-inverses)) at every point of continuity of $s^{\rightarrow}$. Since $0\le s_n(v)\le s(v)+g(v)$ for all $n$, we can apply LDTC to conclude that
$$v s^{-1}(v)+\int^\infty_{s^{-1}(v)}s(u)\,du=\int_0^v s^{-1}(u)\,du$$
at every point of continuity $v$ of $s^{\rightarrow}$. At the other countably many points you can use the fact that $s^{\rightarrow}$ is right continuous.